# NTFS + CreateFile: specify stream offset in pathname?

Tags: winapi, path, filepath, ntfs, createfile

Is it possible to specify stream offset in the pathname when opening a NTFS file data stream via `CreateFile`?

What about if pathname starts with `\\?\`?

E.g. `abcd.txt::$DATA` specifies offset 0 at the unnamed stream*; is it possible to specify a different offset within the pathname**?

*technically, this also means offset equal to stream length in case `WriteFile` is called with append
**without ever making use of `SetFilePointer`

Comment: What would be a use-case for this? Besides homework, I have not ever seen a specification that says: *"Must not use `SetFilePointer`"*.

Comment: Blackbox legacy I/O API that shall not be altered and you have to work around the limitations.

Comment: @IInspectable: the "append" case may actually be useful if you want the application to be able of logging but not corrupting or deleting the log files. Giving the application (its user) only the append access right to the log files should do the job.

Comment: @MartinDrab: But this is handled by [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) already. Just pass a `FILE_APPEND_DATA` [file access right constant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258116.aspx) and you're ready to go. No need to explicitly specify an offset.

Comment: I know. I just wanted to make the "append" thing more clear. I did not plan to bring anything new to the "offset problem".

Comment: You can open a named pipe and pass its path to the program. Not exactly the most elegant solution, but if it does only reading or writing to the file, it could work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no syntax that lets you specify a stream offset in the pathname. See MSDN for the supported syntax:

[File Streams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404.aspx)

You must seek to the desired offset after opening the stream.

Comment: As I expected. Thanks for confirming.